# SWT DRAG and DROP of file type, after Dragging other files are getting deleted

Tags: drag-and-drop, swt, eclipse-rcp, file-transfer

I am dragging the file from a directory to a SWT application, 
My drag Target is CTABFolder, here i dont have drag source, when i drag the file, on drag I load that file to application.

Problem is the rest of the files in the directory are getting deleted.
I am using DROP_MOVE as DND style, on other style I am not able to drop the file.

Please, give me any suggestion about this problem.

Comment: Are you using  DROP_DEFAULT also? A code snippet might be useful to figure out what is wrong

Comment: No, When we use DROP_DEFAULT then we are unable to drop it.